# In Swift how do I only load or use filtered data from a .json file

Tags: json, swift

Ok, so I've been learning how to program in my spare time over the past couple of months and I'm now trying to get my head around how to only use data from a .json file that has been filtered.

For example, let's say I have a .json file in the following format:

```
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "question": "Earth is a:",
             "answers": [
            "Planet",
            "Meteor",
            "Star",
            "Asteroid"
          ],
        "category": "astronomy"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "question":"Which country won the 2006 Soccer World Cup?",
        "answers":[
            "Italy",
            "Germany",
            "France",
            "Brazil"
            ],
        "category": "sport"
 }
```

**My Question**

Assuming I have all my data in a single .json file, how do I load **only** the data that meets a certain criteria, **or** load all the data but then only select the data that meets a certain criteria? Obviously the end result must be that only the filtered data is shuffled and displayed to users.

Apologies if this is obvious, but as I'm a newbie I just don't have the knowledge/experience to find a better way to do this than the multiple files approach I describe below. I did try searching for an answer, but couldn't find one that seems to apply to my scenario. If there is and I've missed it, please refer me to that instead.

**Some context**

At present I'm using the following code to load my data:

```
  func LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers()
    {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("content", ofType: "json")
        let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
        allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
        //println(allEntries)

    }
```

Obviously, the above **loads all of the data** from the .json file. Once this data is loaded I then shuffle all the questions using the following code:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            shuffledQuestions = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(allEntries as [AnyObject])
            nextQuestion++
            LoadQuestion(nextQuestion)

            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }else{

            let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allEntries.count)))
            LoadQuestionPreiOS9(randomNumber)

        }
```

Once shuffled I then present the question to users with the following code:

```
func LoadQuestion(index : Int)
{
    let entry : NSDictionary = shuffledQuestions[index] as! NSDictionary
    let question : NSString = entry.objectForKey("question") as! NSString
    let arr : NSMutableArray = entry.objectForKey("answers") as! NSMutableArray

    let QID : NSString = entry.objectForKey("id") as! NSString

    if let a = arr.objectAtIndex(0) as? String {
        self.answertext = a
    }

    //println(question)
    //println(arr)

    labelQuestion.text = question as String
    labelQID.text = QID as String
```

So, what I would like to do, is give users the option to select the category of questions they want to answer. Now obviously I could do this by using separate .json files for each category and using `if else` statements. For example, I could have an astronomy.json file, a sport.json file, etc and then use code such as:

```
    func LoadChosenCategory()
    {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if (chosencategory == 1)
        {
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("astronomy", ofType: "json")
        let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
        allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
        //println(allEntries)

        }else{

            if (lastchosenchallenge == 2)
            {
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sport", ofType: "json")
        let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
        allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
        //println(allEntries)

            }else{
```

And so on and so on.

But I am sure there must be more efficient ways to do this and I would like to learn how, hence this question.

---

Ok, so I've tried to follow the advice in Russell's answer, but just can't get it to work. It runs fine, but just doesn't seem to actually be filtering the data.

Below is what I've done to try and implement Russell's answer.

First I created a couple of integer variables:

```
var categoryfilter : Int! = 0
var lastcategoryfilter : Int! = 0
```

Then I created a couple of functions for saving and loading the values to NSUserDefaults:

```
func LoadLastCategoryFilter()
{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    lastcategoryfilter = defaults.integerForKey("ChosenCategory")
}


func SaveLastCategoryFilter()
{
    lastcategoryfilter = categoryfilter
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setInteger(lastcategoryfilter, forKey: "ChosenCategory")
}
```

Then I use buttons so the user can set a value for the variables and switch to the 'game' screen:

```
@IBAction func buttonAstronomyCategory(sender: AnyObject) {

    categoryfilter = 1
    SaveLastCategoryFilter()
    ResetGameFromMainMenu()
    switchToMainGameScreen()
}



@IBAction fund buttonSportCategory(sender: AnyObject) {

    categoryfilter = 2
    SaveLastCategoryFilter()
    ResetGameFromMainMenu()
    switchToMainGameScreen()
}
```

And so on for each of the categories.

In the game screen I have a function that loads the lastcategoryfilter value and then I load the .json data as follows:

```
func LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers()
{
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("content", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray


    if (lastcategoryfilter == 1)
    {
        let filteredEntries = allEntries.filter() {$0.category == "astronomy"}
        print(filteredEntries)

    }else{

        if (lastcategoryfilter == 2)
        {
            let filteredEntries = allEntries.filter() {$0.category == "sport"}
            print(filteredEntries)

        }else{
            if (lastcategoryfilter == 3)
            {
                let filteredEntries = allEntries.filter() {$0.category == "History"}
                print(filteredEntries)

            }else{

                if (lastcategoryfilter == 4)
                {
                    let filteredEntries = allEntries.filter() {$0.category == "Politics"}
                    print(filteredEntries)

                }else{

                    if (lastcategoryfilter == 5)
                    {
                        let filteredEntries = allEntries.filter() {$0.category == "Technology"}
                        print(filteredEntries)

                    }}}}}}
```

And then I use the same functions as previously described to shuffle/randomise the questions and present them to the user.

The code all works fine (i.e. no errors) but my data isn't being filtered.

I have no idea where I've gone wrong, but I'm sure it's just a silly newbie mistake! Any suggestions?

Comment: I have to go do some work now - but if you don't have an answer by the time I get home, I will see if I can update your approach a little.  Good luck!

Comment: That'd be great! I seem to be at a loss :(

Answer (score 1):

filtering your array is easy.  Here's a fairly contrived example which doesn't address the JSON or random questions, but does show the filtering part.  Obviously, in your example, you're not going to create named arrays like I have here, but the example works nicely.

```
struct QuestionStruct
{
    var id : Int
    var question : String
    var category : String
    var answer : String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var questions : [QuestionStruct] = []

        questions.append(QuestionStruct(id: 1, question:"question 1", category:"English", answer:"answer 1"))
        questions.append(QuestionStruct(id: 2, question:"question 2", category:"Physics", answer:"answer 2"))
        questions.append(QuestionStruct(id: 3, question:"question 3", category:"Physics", answer:"answer 3"))
        questions.append(QuestionStruct(id: 4, question:"question 4", category:"Maths", answer:"answer 4"))
        questions.append(QuestionStruct(id: 5, question:"question 5", category:"English", answer:"answer 5"))

        let filteredQuestionsPhysics = questions.filter() { $0.category == "Physics" }
        let filteredQuestionsEnglish = questions.filter() { $0.category == "English" }
        let filteredQuestionsMaths = questions.filter() { $0.category == "Maths" }
    }
}
```

more specifically, in your example, you would probably want to amend `LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers` to return a specific list of questions rather than everything.  Thereafter, you can randomise it exactly as before

```
func LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers()
{
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("content", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!
    allEntries = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSArray
    //println(allEntries)
    let filteredEntries = allEntries.filter() {$0.category == categoryFilter}
    println(filteredEntries)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I do appreciate it, but my question is how do I get this to work with .json file like the one used in my scenario?

Comment: Also, in my example the .json file contains multiple answer choices, with the correct answer always being listed first, so I would need to still be able to randomly ask the questions and offer the multiple choices for users.

Comment: in your function `LoadAllQuestionsAndAnswers`, if you pass in a parameter for the category `categoryFilter`, you can return the filtered array instead of `allEntries` - something like `let filteredEntries = allEntries.filter() { $0.category == categoryFilter }`        - loading the data into an array is quite separate from filtering or using it

Comment: Ok, I think I get that. :) I'll have a play with the code and see how I go.

Comment: Ok, so, I've been playing with this for a while and can't seem to get it to work. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, so I've updated the question to include my attempt at following your advice.

Answer (score 1):

OK `Monomeeth` - there are some things we can do to improve the readability and maintainability of your code. For a start - we can remove all of those nested `if` statements and make things a little more generic everywhere.

Although you will have a series of buttons - you can have them all accessing the same method, because you're doing the same thing each time.  if you set the `tag` value of each button to an index value, we will know which button brought us to the method.  If you then store your `categories` in an array, then we don't need to hard-code `Astronomy`, we can just use `categories[0]`

Here are the key bits of code you will need

first get all of your definitions in place

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var categoryFilter : Int = 0
    var lastcategoryfilter : Int = 0

    let categories : [String] = ["Astronomy", "Sport", "History", "Politics", "Technology"] // if you have LOTS of these, you might want to load in a file and parse it ...
    var questions : [QuestionStruct] = [] // QuestionStruct is whatever structure you need to store the questions
    var filteredEntries : [QuestionStruct] = []
```

then you need a single method to handle the button press, which ALL of your category selection buttons are attached to

```
@IBAction func cmdSelectCategory(sender: AnyObject)
{
    // ALL of the buttons for select category are linked to this one method
    // the buttons have a tag value set to act as index

    categoryFilter = sender.tag
    generateFilteredQuestionSet()

}
```

and then you need to filter the questions, based on the `categoryFilter`

```
func generateFilteredQuestionSet()
{
    filteredEntries = questions.filter() { $0.category == categories[categoryFilter]}
    print(filteredEntries)
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this! I've been out all day, so will spend some time now trying to make sense of it all. It does certainly look a lot more efficient than my newbie code did! :)

Comment: Ok, I've tried a few scenarios, but no success. I use one view controller for the main menu where the category selection buttons are, & another where the questions are loaded & the game 'played'. For my latest attempt, in the main menu view controller I've declared the variables (except for questions & filteredEntries) & added the method to handle all the button presses. In the 'game' view controller I've declared all the variables, added my QuestionStruct code, declared the actual categories & added the generateFilteredQuestionSet function. It runs, but doesn't filter & I have no idea why? :(

Comment: By the way, I'm sure this is my fault, not yours! :)

Comment: :-)  it can be hard to find where things are going wrong sometimes - I know that the code I posted works for me as I tested it in a small project.  Does it work for you?

Comment: Well, I can run the whole project in the simulator without any errors. It's just that it's not filtering the data. I mean, the app loads the questions, shuffles them, and displays them one by one. It accurately keeps track of the correct answer. Everything works fine - it's just not filtering the data. Maybe I'll look at it with fresh eyes tomorrow and place it all within the same view controller as a test to see what happens. I'm sorry to have taken up so much of your time. :(

Comment: Ok, this may be a totally dumb question: Do I need to do anything more than `let categories : [String] = ["Astronomy", "Sport", "History", "Politics", "Technology"]` to declare the index value corresponding to the category? All I've been doing is adding tag values to each of my buttons (e.g. 1 for the Astronomy button, 2 for the Sport button, etc) and that's it, assuming that the earlier code dictated the index order by the order the categories were listed. Now I'm wondering if I need to map the index values to their corresponding categories, maybe in my QuestionStruct? I'm a bit lost. :(

Comment: remember the index is always going to be zero-based, so Astronomy is index 0.  You just need to define your categories somewhere - and building the array is as good a place as any, then make sure that the tag (index) of your buttons matches the order in the array